# Can't open programmatically saved Outlook message file

Tags: php, outlook, exchangewebservices

Here is my code for used to save Outlook mail to message file.

```
<?php
    define("FILE_PUT_CONTENTS_ATOMIC_MODE", 0777); 
    /*function __autoload($class_name) {
        $base_path = 'php-ews-master';
        $include_file = $base_path . '/' . str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
        return (file_exists($include_file) ? require_once $include_file : false);
    }
    */
    function __autoload($class_name)
    {
        // Start from the base path and determine the location from the class name,
        $base_path = '.';
        $include_file = $base_path . '/' . str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';

        return (file_exists($include_file) ? require_once $include_file : false);
    }


    /*
    **  Adjust these variables before running the script!
    */
    $server = 'xxx'; 
    $username = 'xx';
    $password = 'xx' ;
    $message_id = 'xx';


    $save_dir = __DIR__; 


    $ews = new ExchangeWebServices($server, $username, $password,ExchangeWebServices::VERSION_2007_SP1);
    //print_r($ews);

    $request = new EWSType_GetItemType();

    $request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
    $request->ItemShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::ALL_PROPERTIES;
    $request->ItemShape->IncludeMimeContent = true;
    //$request->ItemShape->FilterHtmlContent = true;

    $request->ItemIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType();
    $request->ItemIds->ItemId = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
    $request->ItemIds->ItemId->Id = $message_id; 

    $response = $ews->GetItem($request);



    if (($response->ResponseMessages->GetItemResponseMessage->ResponseCode == 'NoError') &&
        ($response->ResponseMessages->GetItemResponseMessage->ResponseClass == 'Success')) {

        file_put_contents($save_dir."/test.msg", base64_decode($response->ResponseMessages->GetItemResponseMessage->Items->Message->MimeContent->_));

    }

    ?>
```

When I'm opening the file, it's getting error message with noticing file permission error on created message file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSG file is a binary (IStorage in case of MSG format) file. That is not what you get from EWS.

Have you tried to open the file in Notepad?

Comment: @damitry
Is there a way to create MSG file as a binary from EWS ?

Comment: I do not believe there is.

Comment: Manually saved file save as a application/CDFV2-corrupt type. Is there any way to save .msg file with that type?

Comment: Can you post the file you get back from EWS?